# How to isolate the drone pipelines when running the same pipeline multiple times concurrently on the same drone runner?

Tags: postgresql, docker, drone.io

I have pipeline that allow concurrency of pipeline, but when the same pipeline run in parallel my pipeline execution will fail in the E2E test. The test fail because test account will race for the session authentication and will logout others account.

I am using puppeteer for E2E testing, so it required to have ip in my test script. And this where is thing things are going wrong as my test connecting to the same docker container instead of the newly created container for the particle pipeline.

```
kind: pipeline
name: Development

concurrency:
  limit: 10

services:
  # start a new postgres database server for the e2e test
  - name: projectdatabase
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: padmin

steps:
  .
  .
  .
  # run the application
  - name: deploy-to-staging
    image: ubuntu
    # run this step container in the background : this so it removed automatically when pipeline execution finished
    detach: true
    commands:
      - cd /drone/src/project/server
      # run the golang executable aka run the project
      - ./server
    depends_on:
      # wait until this steps finish
      - build-frontend
      - build-backend-and-migrate-database

  # run puppeteer end-to-end test
  - name: e2e-test
    image: my-puppeteer-image
    # required because this is private image and doesn't exist in docker.hub
    #
    #
    pull: if-not-exists
    commands:
      # go to puppeteer e2e test
      - cd /drone/src/project/e2e_test
      # install npm modules
      - npm install
      # change the end point from the default/dev-env to the onces created in run application step
      - find /drone/src/project -type f -name "*.js" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/localhost:3535/deploy-to-staging:8080/g'
      # run the tests
      - node test.js


# trigger for dev branch only
trigger:
  branch:
    - dev
```

I am trying to make sure they run isolated pipelines to avoid this E2E test failing.